# How to differentiate react konva elements in the same layer via event.target?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

Good Day,

I'm trying to control a mouseleave event. The goal is to continue the stroke of the `<Drawing>` element when it hits a `<Label>` and stop the stroke when it goes outside the `<Stage>`. The mouseLeaveHandler() on `<Drawing>` stops the stroke when a mouseleave event is fired via setState(). The problem is the mouseleave event is also fired when the stroke goes through the `<Label>` which causes it to stop.

I have tried logging the event objects and the event.currentTarget attribute seems to give me the info I need to differentiate a mouseleave from a `<Label>` Konva.Image and a mouseleave from the `<Stage>`Konva.Stage. However, since the property currentTarget is read-only I can't use it programmatically. The target property is no use since it would show up as the same class Konva.Image.

My question would be, How can I differentiate a konva `<Label>` from a `<Stage>` via the event object? Can I add additional attributes to the event target to make one different from the other?

What I have so far:

```
...
<Stage>
 <Layer>
  <Image />
 </Layer>

 <Layer onMouseMove={(e) => this.onMouseLayerMoveHandler(e)} onMouseEnter={this.onMouseLayerEnterHandler}>
  {/* This is where the Drawing happens */}
  <Drawing
   mode={this.state.isErasing ? 'eraser' : 'brush'}
   brushSize={this.state.brushSize}
   canvasHeight={this.state.canvasHeight}
   canvasWidth={this.state.canvasWidth}
   brushColor={this.state.brushColor}
   hasDrawnHandler={(status) => this.hasDrawnHandler(status)}
   />
   {/* This is where the Label Starts */}
   {this.state.isEditing ? portal : null}
   {this.state.commentsArray.map(comment => {
    let commentValue = comment.value;
    let commentValueArray = commentValue.split(" ");
    let formattedComment = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < commentValueArray.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
       if (i % 10 === 0 && i < commentValueArray.length) {
        formattedComment += '\n';
       }
      }
      formattedComment += " " + (commentValueArray[i] ? commentValueArray[i] : "");
    }

    return (
     <Label
      key={comment.uuid}
      draggable={true}
      x={comment.x}
      y={comment.y}
      width={comment.value.length}
      onDragStart={this.onDragStartHandler}
      onDragEnd={(e) => { this.onDragEndHandler(e, comment) }}
      onMouseEnter={this.onMouseLabelEnterHandler}
      onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLabelLeaveHandler}
     >

    <Tag />
    <Text />

    </Label>
     )
    })}
   </Layer>
</Stage>
...
```

**Drawing.js**

```
mouseLeaveHandler = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  this.setState({ isDrawing: false });
}
```

The first event is when the stroke hits the `<Label>`. Second Is when it leaves the `<Stage>`. As you can see currentTarget have more useful info than the target property

[image: Logs]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.evt.type. When the mouse is outside stage it has a mouseout value when it hits the label it has the mousemove value.